# WSO2 DSS and MS SQL server. Service works extremely slow

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I was faced with a very strange behavior of Data Service Server (v. 3.5.0).

I prepared quite simple service with some resources for MS SQL Server RDBMS data source. When I call one of resources with simple select query I get answer after **6 seconds** (**six seconds**).

The same select in MS SQL Server Management Studio returns data after **15-100 ms**.

The same select in WSO2 DSS Database Explorer returns data after max **15 ms**.

The same select in Netbeans returns data after max 100 ms.

I tried JSTL and Microsoft drivers. The result is the same.

Everywhere except DSS service I get answer in max. 100 milliseconds. Result of these queries is very small - 6-8 rows with about 10 columns.

Which is the reason for such behavior? 
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very, very strange. 
I tried a simple query like:

```
SELECT a1,a2 .... FROM someView WHERE a1=:parameter
```

When parameter is of type STRING (I think, like parameter for PreparedStatement) query returns results in about 4000 milliseconds (???).
If parameter is of type QUERY_STRING query returns results in 10 milliseconds (!!!!). Result is very small - about 10 rows with 5 columns.
Time was measured by net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy, but the same difference I get with pure Microsoft Jdbc and Jtds drivers.

Why such a big difference? 400 times faster?
One question remained: What is to blame:

- WSO2 DSS software?
- JDBC driver?
- SQL Server?